# UPDATE on Objects in Array in AQL ArangoDB

Tags: arrays, object, arangodb, aql

I have a data structure as following:

```
object1.array1[object2.array2[]]
```

I want to remove array2 from object2 or delete all array elements.

Is there a solution for this using AQL-Query?

Answer (score 2):

Demo document:

```
{
  "foo": [
    {"x": [1,2,3], "y": [4,5,6], "z": [7,8,9] },
    {"hello": "world" }
  ],
  "bar": true,
  "_key": "0"
}
```

To remove `foo[0].y` (`[4,5,6]`) with AQL, here is a somewhat generic solution:

```
LET attr = "foo"  // target top-level attribute
LET i = 0         // positive or negative index of target array element
LET subattr = "y" // sub-attribute to remove

LET doc = DOCUMENT("test/0")

LET before = SLICE(doc[attr], 0, i)              // array elements before target
LET middle = UNSET(doc[attr][i], subattr)        // remove sub-attribute from target element
LET after = i == -1 ? [] : SLICE(doc[attr], i+1) // elements after target
LET combined = APPEND(APPEND(before, middle), after)

UPDATE doc WITH { [attr]: combined } IN test
RETURN {NEW, OLD}
```

To remove `"world"` instead, simply change it to `LET i = 1` and `LET subattr = "hello"`.

Comment: Could you tell me, what in details happens here?

LET after = i == -1 ? [] : SLICE(doc[attr], i+1) // elements after target

Comment: As long as `i` is a positive, you can simplify it to `LET after = SLICE(doc[attr], i+1)`. It gets the array elements from `foo` after `i`. I wanted it to work for negative values too, e.g.`LET i = -1` to target the last element of foo (`foo[-1].hello`). The problem is that `i+1 = -1+1 = 0`, resulting in `SLICE(doc[attr], 0)`, which would return **all** elements of `foo`. Therefore, I made use of the ternary operator `? :` (https://cutt.ly/eepqE0M): if i equals -1 then return empty array (there are no elements after the last one), otherwise do usual slicing: `i == -1 ? [] : SLICE(...)`